# Image Location Shuffle

Tags: windows, image, canvas, random, win-universal-app

I am working on a Matching Card Game (Windows Store Application) and I want to shuffle the Images. I Tried randomizing the image.source of the images but it is not working as intended. Is there any way to randomize the location of the Image Control itself rather than randomize the image.source? I Put the Images inside a Canvas if that helps.

Comment: Sure just bind Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top on your Image to properties in your vm that affect it's position . o and place it on a canvas.

Comment: Can you give me a detailed example? I am quite new to the windows application logic

Comment: You should think about approaching the problem in an OOP (Object-Oriented Programming) manner. Create a `List` of Image sources, and then iterate through your list of controls and set the source to be a random item from the list. Once you've taken one from the list, remove it from said list. That might not be the _best_ way to do it, but it's something to get you started. If we write the code for you, then you won't learn anything, come back if you have some code which isn't working as intended.

Comment: @MikeEason Thing is I wrote the randomising code. What I did was create an array of Images, and array of BitmapImages and an array of Bool. After that with a Random variable I was putting the images through the BitmapImages (via bi.Urisource) to the source of my Images. After that I was having problems when I was checking the clicked Image Source. I did the same game in Form Application but there I work with panels and I was rearranging the positions of the Image Boxes and was comparing with Image Box tag. I was wondering how I could do the same with Windows Universal App.

Comment: @MikeEason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312543/canvas-image-shuffle this is the link from what I have done so far but it will not work...