# Canvas Image Shuffle

Tags: windows, image, canvas, random, win-universal-app

So I have a Canvas and a set of 18 Images in it and I want to shuffle the Images

```
foreach (var myImg in GameCanvas.Children.OfType<Image>())
{
    GetTop.Add(Canvas.GetTop(myImg));
    GetLeft.Add(Canvas.GetLeft(myImg));
    listNum++;
    myImg.IsTapEnabled = false;
}
```

I have this part to add the Top and Left of each image in a separate list BUT when I try this

```
foreach (var myImg in GameCanvas.Children.OfType<Image>())
        {           
            int ran = rand.Next(GetTop.Count);
            double Top = GetTop[ran];
            double Left = GetLeft[ran];
            Canvas.SetTop(myImg, Top);
            Canvas.SetLeft(myImg, Left);
            GetTop.Remove(Top);
            GetLeft.Remove(Left);
        }
```

the Images don't change places one box with another as intended. Some Images are lost and it doesn't Show them. Any Idea?

Comment: What is the value of listNum?

Comment: @Taegost logically 17 since I have 18 Images and I start from 0

Comment: I see in the latest version of your code that listNum doesn't matter, it's not used at all.